# python sax: is there a way to halt the parsing from inside a content handler?

Tags: python, sax

Is there a way to halt the parsing from inside a content handler?  Or is throwing an exception the only way?

Note that I am using *xml.sax.parseString*.

Comment: What's wrong with throwing an exception?  I think this is a far better method than polluting the parseString signature with some kind of boolean "keep going if true" return status, or some global variable on the SAX parser that you set to false.  Exceptions can be your friends, just learn to use them properly.

Comment: I agree with Paul McGuire. It's not uncommon to use exceptions for flow control in Python.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire is there a specific exception for this? Or should I just raise an exception and catch it from the scope that called parse()?

Comment: @Petruza - not so much a specific exception *for* this, but you'll need to avoid those exceptions that your SAX parser uses internally. Simplest way to do this is to define your own exception class (be sure to inherit from Exception) and throw one of those.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that methods like startElement() are called from parse() so raising an unhandled exception exits parse().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete API for Python's SAX content handlers is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.handler.html#contenthandler-objects): as you can see, the information flow is entirely one-way, parser to handler -- no way for the handler to supply info back to the parser (such as whether the parse should be terminated).

Therefore, as you had surmised and the commenters confirmed, "control-flow exceptions" are indeed the only way to achieve such a "premature termination". As the commenters mention, it's not too bad, after all.